# Refresh token in Kiota MS Graph SDK for PHP

Tags: php, azure, sdk, kiota

I have Kiota SDK beta MS Grapch for PHP with auth by code. I don't know how add refresh token because now after every reload page application require new auth code. Is posible add refresh token?

```
$tokenRequestContext = new AuthorizationCodeContext(
    'tenantId',
    'clientId',
    'clientSecret',
    'authCode',
    'redirectUri'
);

$scopes = ['User.Read', 'Mail.ReadWrite'];
$graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);

$user = $graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId('[userPrincipalName]')->get()->wait();
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: To add or generate refresh token, the Azure AD Application must have **`offline_access`** API permission granted.

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **auth-code** using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=user.read Mail.ReadWrite offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

***Access token and refresh token got generated successfully*** by using below parameters via Postman.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:user.read Mail.ReadWrite offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

You can **refresh the access token by using refresh token** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:refresh_token
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

***Modify the code by adding the API permission like below:***

```php
$tokenRequestContext = new AuthorizationCodeContext(
    'tenantId',
    'clientId',
    'clientSecret',
    'authCode',
    'redirectUri'
);

$scopes = ['User.Read', 'Mail.ReadWrite', 'offline_access];
$graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);

$user = $graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId('[userPrincipalName]')->get()->wait();
```

Comment: offline_access not help me, I still have to adding auth code after reload page because code is expired

Comment: By default the code will expire after 10 mins and you cannot refresh the code. The user must login to generate code.

Comment: You can refresh the access token but you cannot refresh auth code.

Comment: So how can I use Kiota SDK 2  with refresh token? In MS Graph v1.0 is posible but in SDK v2 I don't see this way.

Comment: Do you want to refresh access token?

Comment: I want use Kiota SDK 2 like MS Graph v1. In Graph v1 I add refresh token to new Graph() and I can use API everytime without login after 10 minutes. I don't know how auth Kiota SDK v2 with token or how use Kiota SDK without generate next code after several minutes.

Comment: @michael6969 Hi Michael, did you manage to find a solution for this?  I am struggling with exactly the same issue.